# How do I use a variable in `where` clause in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I use a variable in the where function ?

I have a **Rate** model with two fields A and B (both integers) and this works :

```
Rate.where('A = 1 and B = 2')
```

How do I pass a variable that I got in params hash ?

```
x = params[:x]
y = params[:y]
Rate.where('A = x and B = y')
```

This doesn't work and returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a simple:
`Rate.where(a: params[:x], b: params[:y])`

It should work fine. It will run a query like below in the database:

```
SELECT rates.* FROM rates WHERE rates.a = 'param_x_value' 
  AND rates.b = 'params_y_value'
```

Use Rails available syntax as much as possible, and avoid string literal.

Comment: This is much preferred over writing SQL snippets for such trivial tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much . agree and noted.

Answer (score 9):

You can use question marks instead of variables and pass those variables as 
the second and third arguments:

```
Rate.where('A = ? and B = ?', x, y)
```

You can use the question marks in any direct SQL query, but I prefer to use [standard AR query syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) with hashes (as @AaditiJain mentioned):

```
Rate.where(a: x, b: y)
```

Comment: is `where` only in Rails?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yes, it is from the activerecord gem.

Comment: @Pushkar, you are fine, but my answer is not only for a this particular case. You can use marks in any sql queries.

Answer (score 8):

@AaditiJain answer is most preferred way of doing.

Another alternative could be using symbols instead of of `?` like follows:

```
Rate.where("A = :x and B = :y", x: params[:x], y: params[:y] )
```

Comment: you can omit curly braces, if hash is the last argument.